# Поменять ссылку this на другую ссылку

Tags: java

Есть два объекта

```
Person p1 = new Person(17);
Person p2= new Person(18);
```

Вызов метода

```
p1.func(p2);
```

А вот и сам метод

```
void func(Person p2){
        this = p2;   //эта строчка не работает, но работает такая: p2 = this;
    }
```

Почему я не могу поменять копию ссылки p1 - this?

Comment: А IDE/компилятор не пишут, почему?

Comment: Потому что `this` это тот объект, чей метод выполняется.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что `this` это контекст. Смена означает смену объекта. this -это не переменная, это объект или место в памяти. this - нельзя изменить.

Ваш пример

```
Person p1 = new Person(17);

Person p2= new Person(18);

p1.func(p2);
void func(Person p2){
    this = p2;
}
```

По существу было бы равно если б можно было

```
Person p1 = new Person(17);

Person p2= new Person(18);

p1 = p2;
```

Comment: А я чет подумал что метод func() относится к классу Person, и речь вроде не об android.  Какой тогда context?)

Comment: this - это ссылка на объект внутри метода объекта. ершы называют также контекстом в некоторых языках.